# Unable to render the chart with custom chart component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts

I am a newbie to react typescript and working on rendering charts with custom components. I have a component called StackedDonutChart which is created with Highcharts

```
`export interface StackedDonutChartProps  {
  data: any[];
  colors: any[];
  size?: number;
};`



 

Object.keys(this.colors).forEach(key => {
         if (this.dashboardStore.systemHealthValueTotals.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
           gaugeData.push({
             name: key,
             value: this.dashboardStore.systemHealthValueTotals[key],
             color: this.colors[key]
           });
         }
       });
```

and passing to my stackedDoutChart component as

```
 <StackedDonutChart 
      data={gaugeData} 
      colors={[this.colors]} />
```

but I could only see the below attached image instead of chart. In the console I could see everything is passing fine like below, and this.colors is having the value of

```
    availability
: 
"#A78D34"
lifecycle
: 
"#E0E0E0"
maintenance
: 
"#00D7D5"
performance
: 
"#0071B8"
```

> : 0 {y: 97, color: '#0071B8'} 1 :  {y: 81, color: '#A78D34'} length :
> 2 [[Prototype]] :  Array(0)

[image]

It is giving the chart like this, even though the data is showing in the console. Please help me with this.

Comment: can you console.log gaugeData and this.colors and include it in the description .

Comment: `let chartData: any[] = [];
 let chartColors: string[] = [];
    
    Object.keys(this.colors).forEach(key => {
      if (this.dashboardStore.systemHealthValueTotals.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const value = this.dashboardStore.systemHealthValueTotals[key];
        const color = this.colors[key];

        chartData.push(value);
        chartColors.push(color);

        gaugeData.push({
          name: key,
          value: value,
          color: color
        }); `                      I tried this and it seems to be working. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to correctly pass colors or other options to the chart using props:

**Demo**: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-typescript-pass-options-using-props-rzgc58?file=/index.tsx

Answer (score 0):

```
let chartData: any[] = [];  
let chartColors: string[] = [];          
Object.keys(this.colors).forEach(key => {       
if(this.dashboardStore.systemHealthValueTotals.hasOwnProperty(key)) {  
const value = this.dashboardStore.systemHealthValueTotals[key];         
const color = this.colors[key];          
chartData.push(value);         
chartColors.push(color);         
gaugeData.push({name: key, value: value, color: color });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).